# Popup position issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a trivia game that has a popup once the question is answered. However, the popup's position is not consistent. I don't know where the problem is. I have been trying many different solutions to no avail.

html:

```
  <div class="logo">
   <img src="css/rio-40.png"/>
</div>
<div class="container" id="start">
  <div class = "question"></div>
  </br>
  <ul id="answers">
  </br>
  </br>
    <li class= "answer span" id= "A"></li>
    <li class= "answer span" id= "B"></li>
    <li class= "answer span" id= "C"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="score"></div>
</div>

<div class="container3">
  <div class = "right-or-wrong" style = "display:none"></div>
  </br>
    <div class = "next" style = "display:none">Next question!</div>
      <div id="score again"></div>
        </div>

<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup-container">
        <p> OH NO! <br /> You got 0 out of 3 correct. <br /> Brush up on your trivia <br /> and play again.</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup1" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup1-container">
    <img src="css/bronze-rio.png" />
    <p> You got 1 out of 3 correct. </br>Good job!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup2" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup2-container">
    <img src="css/silver-rio.png" />
    <p>You got 2 out of 3 correct.</br>Awesome job!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-popup3" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup3-container">
    <img src="css/gold-rio.png" />
            <p>You got 3 out of 3 correct.</br>Perfection!</p>
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
            <li id="reset"><a href="#start">Play Again</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px);
body {
  /*background: ("css/background.png");*/
  background-color:  #21509d;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  height: 600px;
}
.logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

h1{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.question {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  padding-top: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 60px;*/
  width: 75%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 0;
}

#answers{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
/*
#answers ul{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}*/

.answer{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;

}
/*span{
  text-align: center;
}*/
.score {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  width: 30%;
  height:65px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;

}
h2{
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.container3{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*z-index: 10;*/
}
.right-or-wrong {
  padding-top: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 425px;
  width: 90%;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #21509d;
  z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -450px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.next {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  /*margin-left: 620px;*/
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 11;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container{
  /*margin-top: 50px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 0
}
.container2{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*z-index: 10;*/
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}


/*popup if score 0*/
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-popup-container {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 05;
}
/*score 1*/
.cd-popup1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup1.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-popup1-container {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 05;
}
/*score 2*/
.cd-popup2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup2.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-popup2-container {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 05;
}
/*score 3 */
.cd-popup3 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup3.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}


.cd-popup3-container {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 05;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup1-container .cd-buttons:after {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup1-container .cd-buttons li {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup1-container .cd-buttons a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup2-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup2-container .cd-buttons li {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup2-container .cd-buttons a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup3-container .cd-buttons:after {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup3-container .cd-buttons li {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup3-container .cd-buttons a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}


.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup1-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup2-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.cd-popup3-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #F1C203;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
  background: #F1C203;
  border-bottom: .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #F1C203;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

Here is the [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/lafrish/pen/OXoKOj)

And the actual [Game here](https://lafrish.github.io/Trivia/)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the padding and size of the questions and answers. Try making your containers `position: absolute;` and the parent `position: relative;` so they will all be positioned in the same place.